# CAKeyframeAnimation with Path build with CGPathAddArcToPoint doesn't work

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, caanimation, cakeyframeanimation

I have a keyframeAnimation and I define a Path, but the animation doesn't work.

Do you see anything wrong? :S

Here is the code:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *animKF = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

CGMutablePathRef animationPath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(animationPath, NULL, 300, 100);

CGPathAddArcToPoint(animationPath, NULL, 300, 100, 800, 500, 500);

animKF.path = animationPath;

animKF.duration = 3;

animKF.rotationMode =  kCAAnimationRotateAuto;

[imageView.layer addAnimation:animKF forKey:@"keyframe"];
```

Thank you so much

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is happening? Nothing or the wrong thing?

Comment: Also, don't forget to release the animationPath using `CGPathRelease(animationPath);` once you have assigned it to the animation.

Answer (score 0):

You might think that `CGPathMoveToPoint()` is the method that actually "moves" the point, sorry that's not the case. I guess what you intended is to animate "path" property. Hence you should create several (in your case, 3) `CGMutablePathRef` objects as `keyframe`. Then call

```
[animKF setValues: @[path1,path2,path3]];
```